# xUnit testing controller with error when instantiating JWT token provider

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, moq

I have a controller in my WebAPI (not MVC or Core) using .Net 4.8 that I'm trying to test with xUnit.

Before I proceed, the way it is setup may not be correct for unit testing, but it is what I have been given and I don't know any better at this stage, any pointers in this regard is welcome.

The main problem in the controller is the immediate declaration/instantiation of ApiOAuthProvider. As it creates the object, it in-turn does an immediate declaration/instantiation of JwtTokenProvider. This is where the error occurs, inner exception:

> Message "Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot
> find the file specified."

But I'm jumping ahead I'll show the code

**Controller:**

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using TA.Services.BL.BusinessLogic;
using TA.Services.WebAPI.Providers;
using TA.Services.DTO.DTO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TA.Services.BL.Interface;

namespace TA.Services.WebAPI.Controllers
{
  public class AccountsController : ApiController
  {
    private readonly ApiOAuthProvider _jwtTokenProvider = new ApiOAuthProvider();
    private readonly ICommonBL _commonBL;
    private readonly ISystemSettingsBL _systemSettingsBL;

    public AccountsController(ICommonBL commonBL, ISystemSettingsBL systemSettingsBL)
    {
      _commonBL = commonBL;
      _systemSettingsBL = systemSettingsBL;
    }
    ...
    // GET: JwtToken
    [HttpPost]
    //[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
    public JObject Token(User loginUserCredentials)
    {
      // first check the user name & password is valid one before generating token for that user.
      var user = _commonBL.GetUserInformation(loginUserCredentials.UserName);
      var accessToken = _jwtTokenProvider.GenerateToken(user);
      return accessToken;
    }
  }
}
```

**ApiOAuthProvider:**

```
namespace TA.Services.WebAPI.Providers
{
  using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
  using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
  using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Security.Claims;
  using System.Web.Http.Cors;
  using TA.Services.DTO.DTO;
  using static TA.Services.WebAPI.Providers.JWTHelper;

  [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
  public class ApiOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
  {
    private readonly JwtTokenProvider _jwtTokenProvider = new JwtTokenProvider();

    [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
    public JObject GenerateToken(User userDetail)
    {
      ...
      return tokenResponse;
    }
    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName, Status apiData)
    {
      ...
      return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
  }
}
```

**JwtTokenProvider:**

```
namespace TA.Services.WebAPI.Providers
{
  using System;
  using System.Configuration;
  using System.Security.Claims;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Web.Configuration;
  using System.Web;
  using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
  using TA.Services.BL.Interface;
  using TA.Services.DTO.DTO;
  using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
  using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

  public class JwtTokenProvider : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
  {
    private static string plainTextSecurityKey = ((MachineKeySection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/machineKey")).ValidationKey;
    private readonly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainTextSecurityKey));
    private readonly IAuditsBL _auditsBL;

    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
    {
      var signedAndEncodedToken = string.Empty;
      ...
      return signedAndEncodedToken;
    }

    public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string signedAndEncodedToken)
    {
      ClaimsIdentity idenity = null;
      ...
      return new AuthenticationTicket(idenity, new AuthenticationProperties());
    }
  }
}
```

**My xUnit test class:**

```
using Moq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web.Http;
using TA.Services.BL.Interface;
using TA.Services.DTO.DTO;
using TA.Services.WebAPI.Controllers;
using TA.Services.WebAPI.Providers;
using Xunit;

namespace TA.Services.WebAPI.Tests.Controllers
{
  public class AccountsControllerTests : BaseUnitTest
  {
    private readonly Mock<ICommonBL> _commonBLMock;
    private readonly Mock<ISystemSettingsBL> _systemSettingsBLMock;
    private readonly AccountsController _accountsController;

    public AccountsControllerTests()
    {
      _commonBLMock = new Mock<ICommonBL>();
      _systemSettingsBLMock = new Mock<ISystemSettingsBL>();
      _accountsController = new AccountsController(_commonBLMock.Object, _systemSettingsBLMock.Object);
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

The exception occurs here in JwtTokenProvider:

```
private readonly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainTextSecurityKey));
```

**StackTrace:**

```
at TA.Services.WebAPI.Providers.JwtTokenProvider..ctor() in C:\TA\Repos\April 20 2021\TADev\Service\TA.Services\TA.Services.WebAPI\Providers\JwtTokenProvider.cs:line 19 
at TA.Services.WebAPI.Providers.ApiOAuthProvider..ctor() in C:\TA\Repos\April 20 2021\TADev\Service\TA.Services\TA.Services.WebAPI\Providers\ApiOAuthProvider.cs:line 23 
at TA.Services.WebAPI.Controllers.AccountsController..ctor(ICommonBL commonBL, ISystemSettingsBL systemSettingsBL) in C:\TA\Repos\April 20 2021\TADev\Service\TA.Services\TA.Services.WebAPI\Controllers\AccountsController.cs:line 27 
at TA.Services.WebAPI.Tests.Controllers.AccountsControllerTests..ctor() in C:\TA\Repos\April 20 2021\TADev\Service\TA.Services\Testing\TA.Services.WebAPI.Tests\Controllers\AccountsControllerTests.cs:line 26
```

**Sub-questions:**

1. Maybe I'm going down the wrong path, however should I mock ApiOAuthProvider, in order to do that I need to inject it, in order to do that, I need to create an interface and registry it as a service, but this doesn't sound right.
2. Do I just need to create a valid token.
3. Maybe it really can't find the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

**Main Question:** How should I go about resolving this?

**Note:** The application works just fine outside of this test, under normal execution.

**[Update]** Changed controller have ApiOAuthProvider injected

```
  public class AccountsController : ApiController
  {
    private readonly ApiOAuthProvider _jwtTokenProvider;
    private readonly ICommonBL _commonBL;
    private readonly ISystemSettingsBL _systemSettingsBL;

    public AccountsController(ApiOAuthProvider jwtTokenProvider, ICommonBL commonBL, ISystemSettingsBL systemSettingsBL)
    {
      _commonBL = commonBL;
      _systemSettingsBL = systemSettingsBL;
      _jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }
```

Added ApiOAuthProvider to services in startup:

```
services.AddSingleton<ApiOAuthProvider>();
```

Changed test script:

```
  public class AccountsControllerTests : BaseUnitTest
  {
    private readonly Mock<ApiOAuthProvider> _apiOAuthProviderMock;
    private readonly Mock<ICommonBL> _commonBLMock;
    private readonly Mock<ISystemSettingsBL> _systemSettingsBLMock;
    private readonly AccountsController _accountsController;

    public AccountsControllerTests()
    {
      _apiOAuthProviderMock = new Mock<ApiOAuthProvider>();
      _commonBLMock = new Mock<ICommonBL>();
      _systemSettingsBLMock = new Mock<ISystemSettingsBL>();
      _accountsController = new AccountsController(_apiOAuthProviderMock.Object, _commonBLMock.Object, _systemSettingsBLMock.Object);
    }
    ...
```

Debugged the test and it kept going until it got to the same error. Doesn't seem to mock very well without an interface.

**[Update End]**

Comment: You don't need to have interface for injecting in controller constructor. You can inject the class also and can register that class in the serviceCollection. And then you can create mock of the class while unit testing

Comment: ok, nice! So how is that structured instead of: `services.AddSingleton<IAuditsBL, AuditsBL>();` you'd put???

Comment: `services.AddSingletone< ApiOAuthProvider>();` You should use the intellisense to find the best matching method to use

Comment: Made an update above, doesn't seem to mock very well without an interface, but that's only a guess

Comment: In that case you can create your own interface with the needed method in it and implement that interface in your class in addition to the existing inheritance... `public class ApiOAuthProvider : IApiOAuthProvider,  OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`

Comment: I also recommend to have `ApiOAuthProvider` dependent on `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` instead of doing `JwtTokenProvider _jwtTokenProvider = new JwtTokenProvider();`

Comment: I see where your going, thank you Chetan. Make an answer along the lines of 'sort your dependencies out Hank' and I will mark it correct lol

Comment: One more question, if I'm going to make  `ApiOAuthProvider` dependent on `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` then how should I handle the creation of `JwtTokenProvider`?

Comment: You should register it in the service collection.